# What is the name for the process which turned "iced cream" into "ice cream"?

Tags: etymology, nouns, history, participles

There are several words (mostly related to food) which are shortenings of their historical forms. For example, the cold treat *ice cream* was originally known as [*iced cream*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ice+cream) in the 1680s. The *-ed* ending dropped off in about 1744.

A similar example is *skim milk*, which derives from the term *skimmed milk* which is apparently [still in use in the UK](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skimmed_milk). Other examples are *popcorn*, *wax paper* and *whip cream*.

What is the name for the historical process in which the *-ed* ending is dropped? [Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2130) talked about the phonology of this phenomenon, referring to it as *t/d*-dropping, but they did not give a name to the process each word went through. I was thinking that *abbreviation* might work, but is there a specific term available?

Comment: It could be, bastardization...

Comment: @Thursagen, I think your use of comma might qualify, while the change that OP describes does not resemble neither of the processes illustrated in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corruption_%28linguistics%29 (P.S. still it is not far from the sought term so it should be put as an answer, *not as a comment on the question itself*)

Comment: FYI, whipped cream is still in use in the UK too. Not sure about waxed paper...

Comment: @Benjol US still uses whipped cream too, but not everywhere

Comment: @Thursagen, I would have upvoted that comment if it weren't for that comma...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific term for the loss of *-ed* in these contexts. Rather, what you have is the interplay of a few different general trends.

The first factor is simply phonological. *Iced cream*, pronounced very deliberately, has a [stkr] cluster in the middle. In rapid speech, this is going to be reduced to [skr] anyway. The same is true of every other example you gave: if pronounced with the *-ed*, they contain difficult consonant clusters which are likely to be reduced in speech. This is known as [elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision).

The second factor is that English has a highly productive compounding process, which allows you to take any combination of two nouns and stick them together as a new lexical item. Once the phonological elision has taken place, it's immediately tempting to reanalyze the phonological string as a compound word rather than a noun phrase. So now *ice cream* is considered a single lexical item, and has the characteristic first-syllable stress of lexicalized compounds. This is a combination of [reanalysis](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://linguistlessons.blogspot.com/2007/10/morphological-reanalysis.html&ei=2o06TscW4eKIAubAmLYO&usg=AFQjCNFbVjhURey7QLUgo-lB-qq-7m8b-A) and [compounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_%28linguistics%29).

Answer (score 10):

I do not know if there is more specific term (probably there is), but for now I can offer

- morphological [clipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28morphology%29), shortening or truncation
- specifically it is back clipping or [apocope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocope)

in hope that it will bring you closer to the specific term that deals with dropping of *-ed* specifically.