# Is 'steel-toed' shoes acceptable usage?

Tags: word-usage

My father just asked me if I could buy some 'steel-toed' shoes on "the Internet". So I went to [That Popular Shoe Site] and typed 'steel toed shoes' in their search field and it showed me lots of watches, some crampons and various and sundry steel items, but no shoes. When I typed 'steel toe' (without a D) it showed me tons of shoes with steel caps in the toe area. My father and those around him have said 'steel-toed' shoes for as long as I can remember. Is this a generational thing, a regional thing (we're New Englanders) or is steel toed shoes just not correct? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that the shoe manufacturers use "steel-toe", but I've always heard "steel-toed" on the job.

Comment: I might describe it as "steel-capped".  But then, what do I know - I'm British!  And please bear in mind that not only Americans use English Language sites - this 'Little Englander' has no idea what "[That Popular Shoe Site]" refers to.

Comment: Sorry TrevorD - [That Popular Shoe Site] is Zappos. I just didn't want to give them unpaid advertising :)

Comment: As a Canadian, I have heard both "steel-toed shoes" and "steel toe shoes", and even just the colloquial "steel-toes". I don't believe either of them are any more or less correct than the others.

Comment: 'steel-[toe](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toe)' is a noun. 'steel-[toed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toed)' is an adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Steel-toed boot" is an acceptable alternative, both usage-wise and meaning-wise.


Usage-wise, I've heard it both ways in two different states (I grew up in St. Louis, but I go to school in Oklahoma), and [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=steeltoed%2Csteel%20toed%2Csteel%20toe&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csteeltoed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csteel%20toed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csteel%20toe%3B%2Cc0) has that it's used a little less than half as much as steel-toe.


Other validating results include [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/steel-toe_boot), which includes it as an alternative form, and the fact that traditionally they were literally capped, or "toed" with steel.

Answer (score 0):

Ask rather is steel-toe boot acceptable?  No!  I am not an English guru, just a native speaker with a fair ear, so I can give only an argument by analogy.

There is a sloth with three toes.  This is not called a three-toe sloth.  It is called a three-toed sloth. [Wikipedia, Three-toed sloth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-toed_sloth).  [The National Geographic](http://animals.nationalgeographic.com/animals/mammals/three-toed-sloth/) agrees it is three-toed, as does the [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/Three-toed_sloth) (@TrevorD, please note.)

Comment: What happens in one instance doesn't prove what happens in another.  Most people say iced tea, but hardly anyone says iced cream.

Comment: @Steven Littman  True, and when I looked for the difference between iced cream and ice cream, this came up first:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36609/what-is-the-name-for-the-process-which-turned-iced-cream-into-ice-cream

Comment: What @Steven said. Google returns considerably more hits for [***open-back** sandals*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22open-back+sandals%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) than the ***open-backed*** version. In my BrE vernacular the difference is somewhat academic, since in casual conversation probably nobody (including *me!* :) could tell whether I was saying ***steel-cap boots*** or ***steel-capped boots***. I'm not really capable of enunciating another consonant in between /p/ and /b/ like that, and I'd *never* call them "shoes".